# Amplifying signal strength of a u.fl antenna

Tags: antenna, wireless

I have a mini pcie wlan card which uses a mini pcie to pcie x1 adapter card. The adapter card has 2 threaded male connectors which look exactly like conventional rg6 but smaller. Those lead directly to the wlan chip with standard u.fl connectors.

I have an antenna from a netgear router attached to the larger connector.

My question is: what can I do to increase that antennas signal strength?

Alternatively, I have an antenna from a laptop that has a foam spacer and appears to be very intentionally and carefully designed. What can I use to replace or amplify that?

[image][image]

Comment: RG-6 is a type of cable, not a type of connector.

Comment: Are those connectors not RP-SMA? Those are what you'd usually find on a WLAN card.

Comment: Are you wanting to amplify both TX and RX? How would you switch between them?

Comment: I believe it's sma not rp-sma

Comment: If I understand correctly... Tx is transmission and rx is reception. If so, I can only draw a parallel to upload/download. I care mostly for download. My problem is not bandwidth, it's signal range...

Comment: No, that's RP-SMA. https://www.everythingrf.com/community/sma-connectors

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are only downloading files, there needs to be both TX and RX, its not a one way communication like an AM radio. The router is probably using some sort of duplexer for TX and RX, you would basically need another duplexer and 2 amplifiers tuned at different frequencies, most likely an LNA and a PA, I'm sorry but there is no easy solution if you use that antenna.

Probably the easiest solution is to use an antenna with higher gain [high gain antennas](https://www.amazon.com/high-gain-router-antenna/s?k=high%20gain%20router%20antenna), the higher the dBi rating, the higher the gain of the antenna. Instead of hacking your wlan card, use it on the router.